# Delete one and two letter lines in VIM?

Tags: regex, vim

I have a data source that contains a bunch of city names, but mixed in are quite a few state abbreviations that shouldn't be there..

Is there a way in VIM to delete each line than contains two characters or less?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here it is:

```
:g/^\a\{1,2}$/d
```

#### Explanation

- *delete each line that ...* → that calls for a `:global` command (which defaults to `%` range, the entire buffer); the executed command is `:delete`.
- *two characters or less* → in a regular expression, any character is matched by `.`, to restrict this to 1 or 2 the `\{n,m}` multi is used. This still needs to be *anchored* via `^` and `$` to the beginning and end of the line, so that additional characters don't make this match. Oh, and if you also want to remove completely empty lines, change this to `.\{,2}`. See `:help /\{` for details.
- more robust "characters": `.` will match *any* character, i.e. also whitespace. To avoid unwanted matches, it's best to restrict this as much as possible. If your state abbreviations are only alphabetic, you can use the `\a` atom instead of `.` The available character classes start in the help at `:help /\i`.

Comment: The problem is that `.` also matches whitespace, so it won't delete blank lines neither lines with blanks before the abbreviations.

Comment: @Birei: Yeah, the question is vague in this respect and doesn't include example text. I've added a point in my explanation.